# Windows 7 jump list with putty

Tags: windows-7, putty, jumplist

Does anyone know if there is a way that I can create generic jump lists for applications on Windows 7?

Specifically I'd like to be able to pin putty to my start menu, and then create a jump list for all my common servers. I've got no objection to rooting around in the registry to manually create the jump list entries, I was just wondering if it's possible to make a jump list at all.

Comment: Just a suggestion - I've seen a non-ms app that apparently lets you create custom jumplists - Just google it. You can use putty from the command line too so maybe you could add bat files to the jumplist for your different putty connections. putty.exe server.example.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been added to the latest version of putty (0.6.1)! All you need to do is pin to the task bar or start menu and recent sessions are automagically added.

Answer (score 0):

No, as I understand it, the application itself has to support Windows 7 jumplists.